# WordPress AJAX - Yoast primary category ID in functions.php using $_POST

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, yoast

I've been working on an AJAX 'load more' feature for a WordPress category archive page, this one is slightly different though as the client only wants the 'Primary Category' as set by the Yoast SEO plugin.

I have it working correctly on page load but when the user clicks the 'load more' button the page loads posts from all categories, not just the Primary category. It also loads posts that have not been assigned to the category of the page.

I use this function in functions.php to get the category ID:

```
//get cat ID
function getCurrentCatID(){

global $wp_query;
if(is_category()){
    $cat_ID = get_query_var('cat');
}
return $cat_ID;
}
```

The variable `$current_category_ID` is found using this, in category.php:

```
$current_category_ID = getCurrentCatID();
```

I use the following on category.php to get the first 10 posts on page load:

```
$args = array( 
'meta_key' => '_yoast_wpseo_primary_category',
'meta_value' => $current_category_ID,
'posts_per_page' => 10
);

$query = new WP_Query($args); 
//output loop
```

In functions.php, I then use the following to output a new loop to the page, the problems is I can't seem to get the category ID again as a variable.

```
// prepare our arguments for the query
$args = unserialize( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ) );
$args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // we need next page to be loaded
$args['post_status'] = 'publish';
$args['meta_key'] = '_yoast_wpseo_primary_category';
$args['meta_value'] = $cat_ID; //requires variable to be dynamic, hardcoding it works fine
$args['posts_per_page'] = 10;

query_posts( $args );
// new loop
```

I've tried various methods (too many to recall) in the second function using `$_POST['query']` including `$cat_ID = $_POST['query']; $cat_ID = $_GET['page_id'];` or `$cat_ID = $_GET['page_id'];`.

When I `return` the variable to functions.php I always get the value `0`.

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my answer in your question.

how to filter posts by primary category only: Working for me

```
$args = array( 
   'meta_key' => '_yoast_wpseo_primary_category',
   'meta_value' => $current_category_ID,
   'posts_per_page' => 10
);
```

Thanks :)